# Behaviour of == with Generic types

Tags: java, generics, casting, jls

Consider the following snippet:

```java
List<Object> objs1 = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
List<String> strs1 = (List<String>)(List<?>)objs1;

assert strs1 == objs1; //compile error
```

Since `==` only compares the object identity - why is it give compilation error when it is just the matter of cast.

While consider the following snippet - here the assertion does not fail :

```java
String str = "this is it";
Object oo = str;
assert str == oo; //asserts true
```

Here again - we are doing just the same thing but it works fine.

- Why does `==` operator behave on the basis of reference type that is holding the object even when the object being held is the same?

Comment: I think here: **It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).**   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3

Comment: In other words, you had to use a funky cast (you have two casts) to get the compiler to take the assignment.  I think the compiler can't figure out how to do it in one cast, so you get an error.  I tested it and exactly the same error occurs if you use an `if` instead of an `assert`: `if( strs1 == objs1 ) ; //compile error`

Comment: `str == oo` probably works because a String IS_A Object (String extends Object). But a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>` (`List<String>` is _not_ a sub type of `List<Object>`)

Comment: For future reference, questions of this type should include a copy of the compiler error message. To ensure accuracy, use text copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and compare incompatible references at runtime because of type erasure.
Generics appeared in java 5 (named 1.5 at this time) and under the hood the jvm still manage to use `List<Object>` at runtime.
What the compiler say is that `List<Object>` is not comparable with  `List<String>` even if you manipulate the same reference.
In fact semantically a `List<Object>` could not contain a `List<String>` so you came into an illogical situation

The "edge-case" in fact is that you tricked the compiler with the double cast `List<String> strs = (List<String>)(List<?>)objs;`
`List<Object>` is not a `List<String>` as should should not be assigned. On the 2nd line the compiler let you use a cast that shouldn't be possible :

```
    List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList("one", "two"); 
    List<String> strs = (List<String>)(List<?>)objs;// incompatible type affectation with no errors at runtime because of type erasure
    // this compares 2 differents type that the compiler will refuse System.out.println(strs == objs);
```

If you want a super type of both `List<String>` and `List<Object>` it must be `List<? extends Object>` and then the code is correct for both compiler and runtime .

This works and is semantically correct

```
    List<? extends Object> objs = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
    List<String> strs = (List<String>)(List<?>)objs;
    System.out.println(strs == objs);
```

Now speaking of type erasure, it can lead to similar problems:

```
    List<? extends Object> objs = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList((Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(2));
    List<String> strs = (List<String>)objs; // this shouldn't work on runtime but does because of type erasure
    System.out.println(strs == objs);
```

Here I can affect a List of Integer in a List of String variable and I get no classCastException, because of type erasure. If the type protection was perfect, I shouldn't be able 1. to cast A `List<Integer>` to a `List<String>` 2. to affect this value at runtime.

Comment: @user85421 You're right the type inference also use the Left side operand, Object in your case         `List<Object> objs = Arrays.<String>asList("one", "two");` doesn't compile. I will make modifications

Comment: @user85421 thanks that's done, I (wrongly) expected that Arrays.asList(T) will always return List<T> when T types are passed as arguments.

Comment: remember a `String` also is an `Object` - so `T` can be both - usually the compiler would have taken the more specific type, but that is not an option since the assignment would fail

Comment: @User85421 That's the trap String is Object but List String is not List Object as I said its list of ? extends Object that is a superclass of list of String see the usage of extends and super in generics, it's a complex question for a comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: Yes I understand that, I updated my answer to make it clear that this cast shouldn't be possible `List<String> strs = (List<String>)(List<?>)objs` and this is the source of the problem. The compiler refusing to compare incompatible types in not the problem.